# Min and max Uniforms without conditioning

Tags: statistics

Consider $\beta$-centered uniforms $X_1,X_2 \sim Unif(\beta-1/2,\beta+1/2)$ that are independent and identical. Call $U=min(X_1,X_2)$ and $W=max(X_1,X_2)$. How do I find $P(U < x < W)$ for $x$?

Clearly, if $x \not \in (\beta-1/2,\beta+1/2)$ then $P(U<x<W) = 0$. However, assuming that $x \in (\beta-1/2,\beta+1/2)$ would I be able to analytically find a function?

My thoughts so far: by symmetry either $X_1<X_2$ or $X_2<X_1$ so we can do Law of Total Probability. This yields

$P(U < x < W) = P(X_1<x<X_2|X_1<X_2)(1/2)+P(X_2<x<X_1|X_2<X_1)(1/2)$.

But by symmetry

$P(X_1<x<X_2|X_1<X_2)=P(X_2<x<X_1|X_2<X_1)$ so we simply have

$P(U<x<W) = P(X_1<x<X_2)$.

Then by independence of the $X_1,X_2$ we express as

$P(U<x<W)=P(X_1<x)(1-P(X_2<x))=[x-(\beta-1/2)](1-(x-(\beta-1/2)))$.

Is this correct? Another consideration was simply to say that $P(U<x<W) = P(X_1<x<X_2)+P(X_2<x<X_1)$ since the min,max nature seem to suggest we don't need to condition on $X_1<X_2$ cases and can directly add instead?

Comment: I would suggest to find $P(W<x)$ and $P(U>x)$ first.

Comment: @callculus Why? $U$ and $W$ are not independent.

Comment: @kccu You´re right. I was thinking to calculate $P(x_1 <X_i<x_2)$ first.

Answer (score 1):

The second solution is correct.

You have made a mistake in your first solution. Namely, $P(X_1 <x < X_2 \mid X_1 <X_2) \neq P(X_1 < x< X_2)$. So you should instead have $P(U<x<W) =P(X_1<x<X_2 \mid X_1<X_2) = \frac{P(X_1<x<X_2)}{P(X_1<X_2)} = 2P(X_1<x<X_2).$

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to say that you want exactly one of $X_1 \lt x$ and $X_2 \lt x$ to be true

Since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d., this is a binomial probability and so ${2 \choose 1}p^1(1-p)^1 = 2p(1-p)$ where $p=\mathbb P(X_1 \lt x)=\mathbb P(X_2 \lt x) = x-\left(\beta-\frac12\right)$,

Your second attempt used this factor of $2$ and is correct.  Your first lost it and is thus half the correct answer